# Sencha Touch Label - does it have a Tap Event?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to build a flashcard app with sencha touch 2.
I have a label showing the question, which takes up the entire screen, I want it so that when the user taps on the label the answer shows.
Does the label have a 'tap' event? It works when I use a button, but not when I use a label.

Another way around is if I can get the button to be transparent on top of a label.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
label.element.on({
    tap : function(e, t) { ... }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

one more way to bind the tap event to the 'label' control using sencha touch.

```
{
    xtype : 'label',
    html : 'my name is abc',
    listeners : 
    {
        element : 'element',
        tap : function(e, t) 
         {
           alert('1 pressed');
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.Label` is not designed to have a `tap` event. However, you can still achieve it through the `tap` event on your label HTML element, for example:

`label.getContentEl().on{'tap', handler_function,this}`

But **Sencha Touch** does not provide `tap` event on `Ext.Label`, which is a child of `Ext.Component`, so when you try to use tap event on a label, it's not the best practice.

A better approach is to use `Ext.Button` with the following 2 configs:

```
{
  ui: 'plain',
  cls: 'btnCls',
}
```

and in your CSS, style its background to transparent.